# How to insert a result of split word into cells in Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I've got a task to split a line from text file, then put each word from the split result into Excel cells.

I think I've done it right, but it always gives me an exception.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
//baca line lalu split 
xlApp = new excel.Application();
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
xlWs = (excel.Worksheet)xlWb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    textsplit = lines[i].Split('@');
    for (int j = 0; j < textsplit.Length; j++)
    {
        //masukin ke cells
        xlWs.Cells[row, j + 1] = textsplit[j].ToString();
    }
    row++;
}
xlWb.SaveAs(appPath + "testing.xlsx", excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing,
    false, false, excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
xlWb.Close();
closeExcel(xlApp); closeExcel(xlApp);
```

The Exception:

> System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

I don't know what I did wrong.  When I try to insert the cell with hardcode like `xlWs.Cells[1,1] = "a"`, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: At which line do you get the error? and what is the value of `row`?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef  value of row is 1 , and its error at line  " xlWs.Cells[row, j + 1] = textsplit[j].ToString();"

Comment: Can you provide the full error log? Also what is your default language in Control Panel>Regional Setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlWs.Cells[row, j + 1] = textsplit[j].ToString();

I believe you are getting this error because row may have the incorrect value assigned. It may be null?

Try replacing row with your variable "i" from your first loop and it should work fine as I expect you have intended.

Comment: yep after i try with try catch , the data with value "==========================================================" cannot be assign to the cells .. thats why i always get the exceptions , thankyou for the answers